# I have this error with tutorial for conect to App Engine: Hostname '1.myAppIdName.appspot.com' was not verified

Tags: google-app-engine

I tried this tutorial often locally works fine but I still get the same error many times when I try to connect to App Engine

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

The error is: Hostname '1.myAppIdName.appspot.com' was not verified

I activated and billing google cloud, I generated a signed apk and works well google maps but I can not connect to App Engine, I have the same error. I Working with Android Studio, I think I should add something to communicate with https, but can not find anything on google.

Ideas?

**Update:**
I change the address in tutorial, to 1-dot-myAppIdname.appspot.com and give error 400 Bad Request, I delete the instance in App Engine, and tray the tutorial again and now it's working.

Comment: `Hostname ... was not verified` is a typical Android error message when you try to make an https connection with a host who doesn't have a certificate -- search for it (without the ... or quotes) for many hits.  If you DO need https's security, you'll need to add the `secure` parameter to your app.yaml for the relevant urls, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general#https .

Comment: I read the link, I replace the address by 1-dot-myAppIdName.appspot.com and now the error is 400 Bad Request, this means that already connects but there is an error in the request to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate on AppEngine only applies to `*.appspot.com` addresses not for `*.*.appspot.com` addresses.

If version 1 is your default version, then try to connect to `myAppIdName.appspot.com` instead of `1.myAppIdName.appspot.com`.

Comment: is version "1" your default version ? what do you see when you click the 'versions' menu in the GAE console?

Comment: yes it is, now I use 1-dot-myAppIdName.appspot.com and the error is 400 Bad Request in my android app, but I can open it in chrome, alive.

Comment: Ok, so your error changed from "Hostname '1.myAppIdName.appspot.com' was not verified", to "400 Bad request". That means your request is now being processed but something goes wrong while processing the request. But you overcome the original problem, AFAICS.